# How to seed initial state to a saga in MassTransit test harness?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, masstransit

In previous versions of MassTransit, when writing unit tests, I used to seed initial state of a saga by calling the `InMemorySagaRepository.Add()` method:

```cs
private InMemorySagaRepository<TState> Repository { get; }

protected async Task SeedSaga<TState>(TState seedState)
    where TState : class, SagaStateMachineInstance
{
    await Repository.Add(new SagaInstance<TState>(seedState), default);
}
```

This method would add an entry for the saga in the desired state in the repository, which could be used as a starting point for my tests.

Now I upgraded to the version `7.2.1` of MassTransit and this method is no longer available.

Is it possible to seed data in the current version of the `InMemorySagaRepository`? If not, what approach could be taken to achive similar results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There [was a discussion on this](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/discussions/2199) late last year. In summary, you need to be using the container-based in-memory test harness.

```cs
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddMassTransitInMemoryTestHarness(x => 
{
    x.AddSagaStateMachineTestHarness<MySagaStateMachine, MySagaState>();
    x.AddSagaStateMachine<MySagaStateMachine, MySagaState>()
        .InMemoryRepository();
});
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Get and start the test harness (be sure to stop it in *finally*):

```cs
var harness = provider.GetRequiredService<InMemoryTestHarness>();
await harness.Start();
```

You can obtain the saga dictionary and add your seeded saga instance:

```cs
var dictionary = provider.GetRequiredService<IndexedSagaDictionary<MySagaState>>();
dictionary.Add(new SagaInstance(new MySagaState 
{ 
    CorrelationId = ...,
    OtherProperty = ...
}));
```

The linked discussion has some useful extension methods as well.